# unable to join domain using virtualbox

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, active-directory, virtualbox

I'm in the process of setting up a VM environment for a MS certification exam (70-462). Following the training kit's instructions, I've [set up a domain controller (DC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnVVh.png) and [two members (SQL-A, SQL-B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvwZu.png) thus far. I can't figure out why I can't join the domain.

**DC**

```
IPv4 Address . . . : 10.10.10.10(Preferred)
Subnet Mask. . . . : 255.0.0.0
DNS Servers. . . . : ::1
                     127.0.0.1
```

**SQL-A**

```
IPv4 Address . . . : 10.10.10.20(Preferred)
Subnet Mask. . . . : 255.0.0.0
DNS Servers. . . . : 10.10.10.10
```

**SQL-B**

```
IPv4 Address . . . : 10.10.10.30(Preferred)
Subnet Mask. . . . : 255.0.0.0
DNS Servers. . . . : 10.10.10.10
```

I've read [how to do networking between virtual machines in virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox) and [the documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

After trying various network adapter configurations, I can't get them to communicate in order to have the two members join the domain.

When I ping from `.30` to `.10`, I get:

```
> ping 10.10.10.10

Pinging 10.10.10.10 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.10.10.20: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.10.10.20: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.10.10.20: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.10.10.20: Destination host unreachable.
```

Trying to join the domain:

```
> netdom join SQL-A /domain:contso.com

The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

The command failed to complete successfully.
```

Within VirtualBox, I've tried the following combinations for network adapter:

```
Attached to - Promiscuous Mode
-------------------------------
NAT
Bridged Adapter - Deny
Bridged Adapter - Allow VMs
Bridged Adapter - Allow All
Internal Network - Deny
Internal Network - Allow VMs
Internal Network - Allow All
Host-only Adapter - Deny
Host-only Adapter - Allow VMs
Host-only Adapter - Allow All
```

**Edit**

- [`ipconfig /all` of DC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPCEF.png)
- [`ipconfig /all` of SQL-A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0P6p.png)

Comment: Use internal networking unless you need connectivity to external networks and the internet.

Comment: Are all three VMs on the same physical machine?

Comment: @MaxVernon Indeed.

Comment: What does `ipconfig -all` show? (on one of the VMs)

Comment: my suspicion is that the windows firewall on the guests may be blocking this in some capacity

Comment: @swasheck Disabled and still no luck.

Comment: Not necessarily constructive, but if you're on Windows 8 or 8.1 you can use client Hyper-V. It's *substantially* better than virtualbox for this kind of thing - especially vSwitching.

Comment: I generated new MAC addresses for all the VM's through VirtualBox and it resolved the issue.